# method to return more than one array

Tags: java, arrays, return

I have this code

```
public static double[] PDF_CDF_SF(int Sojourn_Time[],double Shape_Factor[],int Num_Analysis_Years){
        double[] CDF=new double[Num_Analysis_Years];
        double[] PDF=new double[Num_Analysis_Years];
        double[] SF=new double[Num_Analysis_Years];
        for(int i=0;i<Num_Analysis_Years;i++){
                CDF[i]=1                    
                SF[i]=1-CDF[i];
                PDF[i]=1;
        }
        return (CDF,SF,BDF);
}
```

Is it possible to return the three Matrix CDF, SF and BDF What you suggest?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend to create a bean to hold the data & return that.

Comment: You should use `double[][]` as return type instead of `double[]`. And please use Java Naming Convention in your code.

Comment: constructor not  be  return type .. but if u wonna return then return in normal methods   more then one  items create list and collection return u can return objs in ArrayList

Comment: Well, I'm glad to see you're at least applying my advice, but you shouldn't modify your existing question to spite the existing answers.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit as it invalidated existing answers. If you have a new question, create a new one (even if it is related), don't fundamentally change your question, if necessary **add** extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return them as ONE array of arrays:

```
public static double[][] PDF_CDF_SF(int Sojourn_Time[], double Shape_Factor[], int Num_Analysis_Years) {
    double[] CDF = new double[Num_Analysis_Years];
    double[] PDF = new double[Num_Analysis_Years];
    double[] SF = new double[Num_Analysis_Years];
    for (int i = 0; i < Num_Analysis_Years; i++) {
        CDF[i] = 1;
        SF[i] = 1 - CDF[i];
        PDF[i] = 1;
    }
    double[][] ret = {CDF, PDF, SF};
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mohammad that work but how I can seperate them to three different arrays

Comment: double [][] result = PDF_CDF_SF(...);
double [] arr1 = result[0];
double [] arr2 = result[1];
double [] arr3 = result[2];

Answer (score 3):

You can't return more than one thing from a function, but you can return a single object that encapsulates them instead.

```
public class Tables {
    private double[] CDF;
    private double[] PDF;
    private double[] SF;

    public Tables(int analysisYears) {
        CDF = new int[analysisYears];
        PDF = new int[analysisYears];
        SF = new int[analysisYears];
    }

}
```

I leave the manipulation and seeding of these arrays as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You were quicker on the draw, but I was about to suggest this same thing.

Answer (score 0):

No. But there are other way to return all arrays:
1) as single two-dimensional array: 

`use double[] result = ArrayUtils.addAll(CDF,SF,BDF);` 
2) put them in another array as its elements

```
double[][] result = new double[3][];
```

3) put them in `List<double[]>`:

```
List<double[]> result = new LinkedList<double[]>();
result.add( CDF );
result.add( CDF );
result.add( CDF );
```

4) as @Makoto answered: use fields